# uWSGI + Nginx (Permission denied) + CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos7, uwsgi

I am trying to mount a flask app using uwsgi and nginx server. I keep getting permission denied error everytime i run my service.

**/home/zerotouch/zerotouch/zerotouch.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

uid=nginx
gid=nginx
socket = /run/uwsgi/zerotouch.sock
chown-socket = zerotouch:nginx
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

**/etc/systemd/system/zerotouch.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve zerotouch
After=network.target

[Service]
User=zerotouch
Group=nginx

WorkingDirectory=/home/zerotouch/zerotouch

Environment="PATH=/home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin"

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown zerotouch:nginx /run/uwsgi; chown zerotouch:nginx /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/activate;'

ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'source /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/activate;/home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/zerotouch.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Error**

```
 systemctl status zerotouch
● zerotouch.service - uWSGI instance to serve zerotouch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/zerotouch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-10-10 16:34:35 CEST; 8s ago
  Process: 28843 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c source /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/activate;/home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/zerotouch.ini (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28839 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown zerotouch:nginx /run/uwsgi; chown zerotouch:nginx /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/activate; (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 28843 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 bash[28843]: detected binary path: /home/zerotouch/zerotouch/env/bin/uwsgi
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 bash[28843]: your processes number limit is 7259
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 bash[28843]: your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 bash[28843]: detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 bash[28843]: lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 bash[28843]: thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Oct 10 16:34:35 faj-poc-1 bash[28843]: bind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 230]
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 systemd[1]: zerotouch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 systemd[1]: Unit zerotouch.service entered failed state.
Oct 10 16:34:35 aj-poc-1 systemd[1]: zerotouch.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

There were problems in permissions for creating and editing a socket.

So I went to /run/uwsgi and used `ls -lhtr` to get overview of file permissions

Then I created a blank sock file zerotouch.sock using `vi zerotouch.sock`

And added permissions to this file for user:zerotouch and group:nginx

```
 chown zerotouch:nginx -R /run/uwsgi
```